# ksh + printf: force input argument to be decimal, not octal

Tags: shell, printf, ksh

Here is my piece of code:

```
MBR=$( printf %02d ${M} )
```

which simply formats the number in `M` into a 2 digit, zero padded number.
This works fine, but sometimes `M` will contain a number that is already zero padded, e.g. `008`

In this case, pritnf thinks that the input number is octal and converts `008` into `00` (as the number 008 does not exist in octal!)

Is there a way to force `printf` to take its input argument as decimal, not octal?

Ksh version: (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2010-06-21
printf version: (AT&T Research) 2009-02-02

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to a current ksh version:

```
$ echo $KSH_VERSION
Version JM 93u+ 2012-02-29
$ M=008
$ MBR=$( printf %02d ${M} )
$ echo $MBR                
08
```

Alternatively, strip off the leading `0`'s

```
$ /usr/bin/printf "%02d\n" $(echo ${M} | sed 's/^00*//')
08
```

or without any external commands:

```
$ typeset -LZ M
...
$ M=008
$ MBR=$( printf %02d ${M} )
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid extra scripting calls (like piping through sed, etc). I guess there is no way of forcing printf directly to take the value as decimal....

Comment: Answer updated for a solution without extra scripting, just declare your variable with `-LZ` typeset options.